# Azure Service Fabric supported OS

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, azure-cli

Is it possible to get a list of Operating Systems supported by Azure Service Fabric cluster in the PowerShell or Azure CLI?

#### Azure CLI documentation

[Official Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/sf/cluster?view=azure-cli-latest#az_sf_cluster_create) documentation provides list of available OS: --os {UbuntuServer1604, WindowsServer1709, WindowsServer1709withContainers, WindowsServer1803withContainers, WindowsServer1809withContainers, WindowsServer2012R2Datacenter, WindowsServer2016Datacenter, WindowsServer2016DatacenterwithContainers, WindowsServer2019Datacenter, WindowsServer2019DatacenterwithContainers}

#### Azure Portal

Portal has updated list of OS:

[image]

#### Service Fabric documentation

Official documentation provides a table of supported OS versions.  [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-versions)

#### Problems

The documentation looks outdated and it is difficult to determine the value of a parameter for the Azure CLI command from the parameter name.

I want to use "WindowsServer datacenter-core-1909-with-containers" but can't figure out the --os parameter value to achieve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, PowerShell and CLI both don't support OS `WindowsServer datacenter-core-1909-with-containers`, it is clear in the doc.

For the latest powershell [`New-AzServiceFabricCluster`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.servicefabric/new-azservicefabriccluster?view=azps-5.9.0#parameters):

[image]

For the latest CLI [`az sf cluster create`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/sf/cluster?view=azure-cli-latest#az_sf_cluster_create-optional-parameters):

[image]